# Password strength enforcement on linux

Tags: linux, password

How can I enforce mínimum length and complexity for users passwords on Linux?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look into all things "pam" and particularly the `pam_passwdqc.so` module  which stands for Pluggable Authentication Modules".   Man page here: http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_passwdqc Article here: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6111316.html

This little perl one liner will do set password quality as per the NSA Securing Linux Guide:

```
perl -p -i.prekickstart -e 'BEGIN {print stderr "Configure password quality module\n";}  \
                s{(^password\s+requisite\s+)(pam_cracklib.so)(.*)}{$1 pam_passwdqc.so min=disabled,disabled,16,12,8} ;' /etc/pam.d/system-auth
```

(Tested on RedHat/Centos).

Answer (score 2):

[RedHat Kbase for password length and complexity](http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-2719)

one more link i have use log back may be help [stronger Password](http://www.puschitz.com/SecuringLinux.shtml#EnforcingStrongerPasswords)